# Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object

Tags: matlab

With this code I try to read out a text file with 3 column and a lot of rows. I am interested on the first column. I'm trying to convert a cell to a matrix with cell2mat, but it doesn't work. Why?

Error:

> Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.
>   Error in cell2mat (line 42)
>   cellclass = class(c{1});

```
fid=fopen('myfile123.txt');
C=textscan(fid,'%s %s %s');
C_1=str2double(C{1,1}); % first column of the cell
fclose(fid);
myCell=C_1; % 
A=cell2mat(C_1)
```

Comment: `cell2mat` expects a cell array input, `C_1` is a double.

Comment: The problem is the C_1 is not a cell, (type `whos C_1` to see). When you reference `C` using curly braces, you are copying the contents of the first cell, then converting it from a string to a double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is occurring because `C_1` is a double and not a cell when you try to convert it from a cell array to a matrix. Using str2double on a cell array containing only doubles will create a matrix as you want, without the need for `cell2mat` afterward.

Moreover, if you want to access ALL the rows of the 1st column of the cell array you need to use the colon operator like so:

```
myCell = C_1(:) %// All the rows of the 1st column. Check the docs about referencing in cell arrays for the difference between regular braces and curly braces.
```

So to sum up your code would look like this:

```
fid=fopen('myfile123.txt');
C=textscan(fid,'%s %s %s');

C_1=str2double(C(:,1)); % first column of the cell. using str2double transforms the cell array into a matrix of double, so there is no need for cell2mat afterwards.

fclose(fid);
myCell=C_1;
```

Comment: But If I already created a Matrix after the this lineC_1=str2double(C(:,1));  why do I need this one? myCell=C_1;

Comment: now I want to plot these values from this column. 
plot(С_1(:,1)). Error: using plot
Too many input arguments. Why is it not correct?

Comment: I just added myCell = C_1 because it was in your code above but its not necessary.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted for future reference. As for your new question, what is the output of size(C_1(:,1)) ?

Comment: The output of size(C_1(:,1)) ans =

     6     1. If I enter  C_1(:,1) I see all values of the first column. Why is it not possible to plot?

Comment: No problem! That's the green check mark just below the arrows at the top of the answer. As for the error maybe you need to use C_1{:,1}. If that does not work can you edit you question and post its content, or the output of 'whos'?